# Python sorted() throws error if map and lambda combination is given for the key keyword argument

Tags: python

```
>>> def last_letter(s):
...   return s[-1]
...
>>> sorted(['ghi', 'def', 'abc'], key=last_letter)
['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

But,

```
>>> sorted(['ghi', 'def', 'abc'], key=map(lambda f: f[-1], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']))

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

I can see the **map**() returns the expected values

```
>>> map(lambda f: f[-1], ['abc', 'def', 'ghi'])
['c', 'f', 'i']
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Comment: `map` creates an iterator / list whereas `key` should be a function. The result of a function is not equal to the function itself.

Comment: What do you expect this to do…?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `key` argument to your call to `sorted` needs to be a function. Instead, you're currently giving it the *result* of a function call. Try `sorted(['ghi', 'def', 'abc'], key=lambda f:f[-1])`

Answer (score 1):

You can't to use a map as a `lambda` function, the strings in the list are automatically passed to the `lambda` and the operation defined in the `lambda` will be executed and the result will be returned, simply use it like this:

```
print(sorted(['ghi', 'def', 'abc'], key = lambda f: f[-1])) # ==> ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```